# Is there a way to get the HTTP response header in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using a control fileUploader to upload files.

Somehow the control does not give me the HTTP response.

Is there a way in Javascript, where in I DO NOT have the instance of XMLHttpRequest, but still can get the response of all HTTP Calls?

Comment: Are you sure that `fileUploader` doesn't provide you some way of getting the `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: yes...unfortunately there is no way I could get the instance of XMLHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it by modifying XHR's prototype so that `addEventListener` adds a listener wrapped in a function that also dumps the headers to the console (or does something else useful with them).

This is completely untested, but should hopefully get the point across.

```
var ael = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener = function(e, f, g) { 
  var xhr = this;
  var args = arguments; 
  function fn() {
    try { 
        console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); // or whatever
    } catch (err) { }
    return f.apply(xhr, args);
  }
  return ael.call(this, e, fn, g);
}
```